# Clip a YouTube video without having to download entire length beforehand

Tags: youtube, video, image-manipulation

I would like to clip a YouTube video say from **x** minute to **y** minute and download it into my desktop computer.

Currently I'm having to download the entire video and then use a video editor for clipping. In most situations, I would like to clip under 60 seconds from a 15-minute video. Downloading the entire video in this case is time consuming.

Is there a way to download only a portion of a YouTube video without having to download the entire thing to trim locally?

Answer (score 1):

With free desktop tools like [BB FlashBack Express](http://www.bbsoftware.co.uk/BBFlashBackExpress/Home.aspx) and [Microsoft Expression Encoder Screen Capture](http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/how-to-record-a-screencast-with-expression-encoder-4/), you can record whatever is running on your screen. While the video is running, you can start & stop at required portions.

With [Expression Encoder SP2](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27870), you can overcome the 10-minute screen capture time limitation that was there earlier.

You can also use open-source tools like [FFmpeg](http://wiki.oz9aec.net/index.php/High_quality_screen_capture_with_Ffmpeg) & [recordMyDesktop](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/about.php) to record video playing on the desktop.